# Is there any time tracker that is aware of Unity workspaces?

Tags: compiz, workspaces, time-management

Hamster is [unable to detect](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hamster-applet/+bug/529687) my four Unity 3D workspaces:

[image: screenshot]

Is there currently any time tracker that can?

Comment: Hi! I apologize if this is not the right place to post this. Did you find a solution? I just found out about hamster and it would be  a lot more useful and useable if this functionality worked in a standard ubuntu installation (Unity 3D, compiz whatnot)

Comment: @leugim I'm still monitoring this page and will keep it updated if I learn of a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.

Source: Absence of responses to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Just checked on LaunchPad and it is still a known bug within Hamster.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hamster-applet/+bug/529687